# How to paste the data in another workbook by yerterday date using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am genarating some data in excel let say B3 to b8 and I would like to paste the rows into mastersheet under a yesterday column. Like example: master sheet having dates like 
2/20/2018 2/21/2018 in A1 and B1 column.
I want paste the data under 2/20/2018 that means I want publish the data under yesterday date.
Can some please help on this..

Comment: Having a column per date could get messy. What about each row starting with a date, so that each row resembles a database record. Then it's really easy to look at data for just one date or even for a range of dates. You can do what you're describing with VBA but it would be a clunky experience - you paste data then it gets moved somewhere else. If you're still stuck tomorrow maybe I can help more usefully.

Comment: Hi Scott,    in mastersheet each column having date and daily basis I have to update the data in respective date. Means I have to update data under yesterday's date

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
If DateAdd("d", -1, Date)= ActiveSheet.Range("") Then 'Address the date cell 
    'Do something
End If
```

Comment: Using the IF condition I showed in the answer, along with the simple copy-paste should do the trick for you. Here's a reference, for your code
[Range.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel)